# Remember me is not working in PHP

Tags: php

When I try to login with username and password with checked option of remember me, and when I logged in and once again go back to login page I does not see username and password there, why it is so what I'm doing wrong???

```
<?php
$title   = "Login Page";
$heading = "Login Form";
include "includes/home_page_header.php";
?>
<?php
$cookie_username = $cookie_password = "";


if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";die;
    if(!empty($_POST['cookie_username']) && !empty($_POST['cookie_password']))
    {
        $cookie_username = $_POST["cookie_username"]; 
        $cookie_password = $_POST["cookie_password"];
$sql_users="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$res_users = mysqli_query($link,$sql_users);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res_users) > 0 )
       {      
              $_SESSION["Username"]= $cookie_username;
              $_SESSION["Password"]= $cookie_password; 
              header('Location:http://localhost/sample/home_page.php');         
       }
       else
       {
            echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
       }
    }


if($_POST['rememberMe'] =='on')
{       
    setcookie('cookie_username', $cookie_username, time() + (86400 * 30));
    setcookie('cookie_password', $cookie_password, time() + (86400 * 30));
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_username']))
    {
        echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_username . "' is not set!";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_username . "' is set!<br>";
        echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['cookie_username'];
    }        
}
}
?>

<table class="login_table">
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
<tr>
<td>User Name :-</td>
<td><input type="text" name="cookie_username" value="<?php echo $cookie_username;?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :-</td>
<td><input type="password" name="cookie_password" value="<?php echo $cookie_password;?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    }
    else {
        echo '';
    }
    ?> >Remember Me
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Never store a password in a cookie.

Comment: Your `$cookie_username` variable is only set if you come from login page, but not if you enter it again.

Comment: Login and Session systems are very sensitive. There is much logic and discussion about best practices. Based on your question, I would suggest you first learn about basic encryption methods, sanitation, and proper sensitive data storage techniques.

Comment: I don't see you setting the 'remember' cookie anywhere so `isset($_COOKIE['remember'])` will always be false.

Answer (score 2):

**Please do not store sensitive data in cookies**

---

The remember me functionality should contain something like a token which is generated each time someone logs in, then that can be compared with the database. If the user wants their username/password remembering in the form this should be done client site by clicking "Remember my login details" when they login.

Anyway, to answer your question..

When the page is loaded, you're setting the username/password variables as empty

```
$cookie_username = $cookie_password = "";
```

You should change this line to something like

```
$cookie_username = isset($_COOKIE['cookie_username']) ? $_COOKIE['cookie_username'] : '';
$cookie_password = isset($_COOKIE['cookie_password']) ? $_COOKIE['cookie_password'] : '';
```

Also, please change your checkbox to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="on" <?=isset($_COOKIE['rememberMe']) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're collecting the input box with the name 'rememberMe' however you aren't posting an input named 'rememberMe'

```
if($_POST['rememberMe'] =='on')
```

You're posting 'remember' and collecting 'rememberMe'

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="remember"
```

So either change:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="remember"
```

To

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"
```

Or

```
 if($_POST['rememberMe'] =='on')
```

to

```
if($_POST['remember'] =='on')
```

Also, you probably shouldn't store sensitive information in cookies; give [THIS](http://wonko.com/post/why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-cookies-to-store-session-data) a read.